# Get json data in VueJS

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs3

```
onMounted(() => {
  productService.value
    .getProducts()
    .then((data) => (products.value = data));

  console.log((products))
});
```

When I print *products* with console.log, here what I have.

[capture of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpGvw.png)

I see that the data I want are in RawValue but I don't know how to access them.
I tried Object.values(products) or just console.log(products._rawValue) or console.log(products.rawValue) it print *undefined*.

Do you know what function call ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to define variables in the data property and fill them with incoming data.

Comment: How I fill them with the incoming data ?

Comment: Try console logging 'data' to verify it's structure.  You may actually need to set 'products' (or 'products.value') to a property of data i.e. something like ```products.value = data.products```.

Comment: Hi @KateP, I just wanted to make sure, is this data coming from `firebase`? **P.S.** It will really help us if you tell us what package are you using to receive that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues

#1 - you're using `console.log(products)` which shows you the reactive object, what you need instead is `console.log(products.value)` which will only show the value, which should match the content of `data.produtcs`

#2 - you might find that  now shows an empty result. The reason that's happening is that you're calling the console log after the async function, but before it finishes, so you're calling it before it has a chance to update. To fix that, you can log as part of the async function

```js
onMounted(() => {
  productService.value
    .getProducts()
    .then((data) => {
      products.value = data;
      console.log(products.value);
    })
});
```

If you're using the `products` inside a template, you don't need to worry about what's before or after the async function since it will re-render the component on change.

Also, you probably don't need to define `productService` as a `ref`, the class is likely not something that needs to be reactive, so you can just do simple assignment and then skip the `.value` to call `getProducts`

Comment: Thank you very much it worked ! Indeed I was trying products.value but it was showing an empty result, now placed where you said it's fine

Answer (score 0):

with axios what I do is take out the data with response.data you could try

```
                    onMounted(() => { 
                    productService.value.getProducts().then((response) => (
                        products = response.data
                        )); 
                        console.log(products.length); 
                });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunatly it doesn't work because products is not directly the array but in products there is the array in rawValue

Comment: try with onMounted(() => {
  productService.value
    .getProducts()
    .then((response) => (products= response.data));

  console.log(products);
});